# UK Spousal Visa Refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, spouses

I was in the UK for seven months.
I arrived in UK with my husband (who is a British citizen) on August 11, 2018 after our wedding on August 4,2018.
We applied for the Spousal Visa on January 1, 2019. 
 I received my refusal letter on a Saturday, February 23, 2019. The letter said to count it as receiving it two working days later (February 26, 2019) 
I had 14 days to appeal or I had to leave the country. I decided to leave the country but I couldn’t at the time because the Home Office didn’t return my passport with the refusal letter.

I left on March 23, 2019 using the Voluntary Return Service BUT I paid for my own flight back to the U.S.

I am afraid that my second visa application will be refused again because I overstayed my six months visit. I’m also afraid I might have a re entry ban because I used the VRS and overstayed.

Any advice on what we should do? I’m currently in the process of reapplying from the US.

Comment: This is not a question for [travel.se]. Questions about long term migration, including family visas, belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: Voluntary departure at person’s own expense
**Unless they are applying for entry clearance as a family member** (under Appendix FM of the Immigration Rules), or they were under 18 at the time of their most recent breach (as set out at paragraphs A320 and 320(7B) of the Immigration Rules), the following categories of offender will ordinarily be subject to a mandatory one year re-entry ban if they leave the UK voluntarily at their own expense:

Comment: Since you’re applying as a family member, **it appears** you don’t have a ban. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf#page5

Comment: You can use borderforcecomplaints@homeoffice.gov.uk or complaints@homeoffice.gov.uk to confirm if you have a ban.